# How to get data of 2nd table yii find all criteria join

Tags: php, mysql, yii, findall

This is companycontent model relations:

```
public function relations() {
            return array(
                'company_content_lang' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CompanyContentLang', 'company_content_id'),
            );
        }
```

This is my query:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select='t.tab_content, mv.label AS label, t.is_active';
    $criteria ->join='INNER JOIN master_value as mv 
                      on mv.value = t.tab_type 
                      AND value_code = "tab_content" 
                      AND locale = "' . Yii::app()->language  . '"';
    $criteria ->condition = 'company_id = :company_id AND is_deleted =0';      
    $criteria ->params=array(':company_id' => (int) $id);     
    $criteria->order='mv.order';
    $modelContent = CompanyContent::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Relationship between company_content and master_value is `company_content.tab_type = master_value.value AND master_value.value_code='tab_content'`. So I can't make this relation in company_content model.

Please show me how to  get `"mv.label AS label"`  value.

Comment: I've no clue about yii, but aren't you missing a `FROM` clause?

Comment: Display your tables & Also post the model `relations()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your table structure is but have you considered defining the relationship between t and mv in the CompanyContent model relations() ?

Comment: @all Thanks for your comments. I edited it. I hope you understant :)

Comment: @fancyPants I think don't need FROM when I use CompanyContent::model()->findAll($criteria)? Maybe I wrong? :s

Comment: You just post the function relation() in your model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, show us the relations() at CompanyContent model.

Usually, it's just a simple thing. Just add public property/variable inside the CompanyContent, ex:

```
class CompanyContent extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $label; //added

...
```